# Sharing news between $2^n$ people

Tags: algorithms

Assume that $2^n$ people want to share their news with each other. Each person has some news that the other persons aren't aware of them.
The process of sharing news consists of some steps. At each step, each person can share his/her news with $1$ person at most. So, If person $A$ and person $B$ contact each other at step $i$, Then after step $i$ is finished, they now both their news and the other one's news. ($A$ nows his/her news and $B$'s news, for example)

Propose a divide and conquer algorithm for the process of news sharing such that the process finishes at the minimum number of steps. (Note that each person should know all of the news after the algorithm is finished.)

Note: I don't know how to divide these people. Just dividing by two? What happens next? Will the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First think of one piece of news, say the one A has at the start.  In the first step A tells B.  Now two people know it.  In the second step they each tell one other person.  Now four people know it.   You should be able to convince yourself that $n$ steps are required to spread the news and that you can do it in that many.

For everybody having news, clearly at least $n$ steps are required.  You should divide the group into $n/2$ pairs at each step.  Your task is to describe how the pairs are selected at each step.  It might help you to do it by hand for eight people.  The first step you can divide them randomly into pairs.  Record which pieces of news each person knows.  You want to make sure that nobody talks with somebody with whom they already share a piece of news.

The divide and conquer requirement is a big hint.  Suppose you had a way to handle $2^{n-1}$ people in ${n-1}$ rounds.  How could you use that to handle $2^n$ people in $n$ rounds?  Clearly you can handle $2^0=1$ people in $0$ rounds because the only person already knows the only piece of news.

Comment: I know that this algorithm works because i applied it to some examples. But, I need to prove that its correct. Also, I don't see a divide and conquer approach in your way of solving the problem. It seems like we just pick someone who we didn't speak to, in the previous steps, and we tell our news to him. How is dividing the people to groups with $n/2$ members, used?

Comment: You divide them into groups of $2^{n-1}$, not $n/2$.  It clearly works for $n=2^1=2$ people as they just have to meet in $n=1$ round.  Now assume it works for $2^k$ in $k$ rounds.  Given a group of $2^{k+1}$, divide them into two groups of $2^k$.  Use the solution that we assumed exists on each group.  Now everybody in each group knows all $2^k$ secrets from their group.  Pair up the members from the two groups for the last round and everybody knows everything in $k+1$ rounds.  This is a typical proof by induction.